# Power Query issues after initial run of the query

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a fairly simply power query built that collects data from 12 sheets in a single workbook and consolidates them into a master list.

- The data/columns are consistent across this workbook
- The initial run of the query works fine

Issues:

- After the initial run the query adds more lines instead of re-running and updating

I deleted the sheet containing the query return thinking it would re-run and populate the data I want but now nothing happens. When I attempt to run the query I get an error that reads: ***"You cannot refresh a connection-only query"***

**How do I either:**

- Avoid the initial replication problem
- Delete the output and re-run the query, basically how do I get past the "cannot refresh error"?

Query details:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection only query will not refresh unless there is another query that is dependent on it. If you want to refresh it, you must change it to output to the workbook or to the power pivot data model.

In Excel, use Data>Queries & Connections. Right-click the query you want to refresh and choose Load To

[image]

Select an appropriate destination for your query results.

You may want to choose 'Table':

[image]

With regards to the "replication problem", it's a little difficult to say without seeing:

1. your connections properties window and
2. the full text of the Advanced Editor in the Power Query Editor window

You should probably experiment with different settings in the connections properties window. Use Data>Queries & Connections>Properties to show the window in the image below, then try refreshing your query under different options.

[image]

Comment: This got me where I needed to be. Appreciate it. I will mess with the refresh options and test. The "Overwrite existing cells with new data, clear unused cells" option looks promising.